# $\int ^{0}_{-2}\int ^{x+6}_{-2x}\dfrac {y+2x}{\left( y-x\right) ^{3}}\cos \left( y-x\right) dydx$

Tags: integration, analysis

$\int ^{0}_{-2}\int ^{x+6}_{-2x}\dfrac {y+2x}{\left( y-x\right) ^{3}}\cos \left( y-x\right) dydx$

How to calculate thus integral? I tried let y-x=u but i couldn't calculate .

Comment: You need two variables to change, not just one substitution. Try also $v = y+2x$ with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: when you are done drawing your domain in the $uv$ plane your integral should look something like

$$\int_0^6 \int_0^u \frac{v\cos u}{3u^3}\:dv\:du$$

however, your integral does not converge. You should check to see if what you posted is correct.

Comment: I understand. But ı couldnt calculate cosu/u . The question is right.

Comment: @FMath ...that's because the integral doesn't exist. I already said this. If the denominator was squared instead of cubed, for example, the integral would converge. It would converge for any power less than $3$